# which method is used to generate "Application.config.secret_token = '...'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2, every app's `config/secret_token.rb` has a `secret_token`:

```
ProjectName::Application.config.secret_token = 'c9d1a7ea24444ddf06e4b52a7a08174fc9bc7483727b8ec674d6360f2fb93db007114971feeb1e0f69d6dda595dafb30956b057962aad44a137295128a6d23c0'
```

I am curious that which method `Rails` used to generate the 128-bit code: `c9d1a7ea24444ddf06e4b52a7a08174fc9bc7483727b8ec674d6360f2fb93db007114971feeb1e0f69d6dda595dafb30956b057962aad44a137295128a6d23c0` . I tried `SecureRandom`, but it seems not have such method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `SecureRandom.hex(128)`

http://www.jamesbadger.ca/2012/12/18/generate-new-secret-token/